# Loop through divs with same class and compare with divs from other class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare the content of two divs, and if the content is the same, hide the first one. Here is what I'm doing (works):

```
<div class="summary" id="para1">{{safe this.summary }}</div>

<div class="content" id="para2">{{safe this.body.value }}</div>

   function(){ 

  // get text from paragraph 1
  var text1 = document.getElementById("para1").innerText;
  // get text from paragraph 2
  var text2 = document.getElementById("para2").innerText;

  // get first 100 caracters from paragraph 1
  var firstTwentyText1 = text1.substr(0, 20);

  // get first 100 caracters from paragraph 2
  var firstTwentyText2 = text2.substr(0, 20);

  //if the first 100 caracters of the paragraphs are the same
  if ( firstTwentyText1 == firstTwentyText2 ) {
     // then it hides the first paragraph
     $("#para1").each(function(){
     document.getElementById("para1").style.display="none";});

  } else { 

    console.log("nothing found"); 
  }

}
```

The problem is, there are multiple divs on the same page, so I need to use class instead of id and loop through each and compare. Here is my draft:

```
<div class="summary para1">{{safe this.summary }}</div>

<div class="content para2">{{safe this.body.value }}</div>

  function() {

  // get text from paragraph 1
  var text1 = document.getElementsByClassName("summary");

  for (var i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {
    var eachtext1 = text1[i].innerText;
    // get first 100 caracters from paragraph 1
    var firstText1 = eachtext1.substr(0, 20);
  }


  // get text from paragraph 2
  var text2 = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

  for (var i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {
    var eachtext2 = text2[i].innerText;
    get first 100 caracters from paragraph 1
    var firstText2 = eachtext2.substr(0, 20);
  }

  // if the first 100 caracters of the paragraphs are the same
  if (firstText1 == firstText2) {
    // then it hides the first paragraph for all content

    document.getElementsByClassName("para1").style.display = "none";

  } else {

    console.log("nothing found");
  }

}
```

Do you guys know how to do that? A little help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the HTML also?

Comment: why use `setInterval` here?

Comment: I suggest to use jQuery to select and iterate through elements instead of messy javascript code

Comment: And it will become messy jQuery code.

Comment: I'd like to hide the content of class="summary" if it's the same as the content of class="content"

Comment: Question: Have summary and content elements a wrapper element?As side note: Multiple classes for the same element should be written with a space like `<div class="content para2">` not `<div class="content" class="para2">`.

Comment: Thanks caramba for your reply and the tip, I've corrected the edit. No they don't have a wrapper element.

Comment: If one of `summary div's` have same test as one of `content div's`, you need to hide all `summary div's` or only one that have same text?

Comment: there's not only 1 summary div and content div on the page, they all get generated automatically. so I need to compare summary with content for each article-section

Comment: Here is how it gets generated : <div class="article-section><div class="summary"></div><div class="content"></div></div>. So basically, I need for each article-section to compare summary div and content div, and if same, hide summary div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simpler way to my problem, here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

console.log( 'code is loaded');

var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function(){

    if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 5000){

        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    $(".article-section.section-type-article_section").each(function(){  

        var summary = $(this).find(".summary"); 
        var content = $(this).find(".content") ; 

        if(summary.text().trim() == content.text().trim()){ 
             console.log( 'found article summary with same content');
            summary.hide();
        } 
    }); 

}, 10);     

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code for classes

```
  for (var i = 0; i < text1.length; i++) {
    var eachtext1 = text1[i].innerText;
    // get first 100 caracters from paragraph 1
    var firstText1 = eachtext1.substr(0, 20);
  }
```

you always rewriting variable `firstText1`. After this loop `firstText1` will hold first 20 char from last div, not from all divs (same for test2).
You should save texts (20 chars) in array and then compare.

Try this:

```
var summarys = document.getElementsByClassName("summary");
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

function get_first_20_chars( node ){
    var content = 'textContent' in node ? node.textContent : node.innerText; //still support ie8?
    var char20 = content.substr(0, 20);
    return char20
}

var char20_of_contents = [];
for( var i = 0, l=contents.length; i<l; i++ ){
    char20_of_contents[i] = get_first_20_chars( contents[i] ); 
}


var found = false;
for( var i = 0, l=summarys.length; i<l; i++ ){
    var summ_node = summarys[i];
    var char20_of_summ = get_first_20_chars( summ_node );
    if( char20_of_contents.some( function( content_char_20 ){ return content_char_20 === char20_of_summ; } ) ){
        summ_node.style.display = 'none';
        console.log( 'found node with same content', summ_node );
        found = true;
    }
}

if( ! found )
    console.log( 'nothing found' );
```

This code check every `summary` div. If div have same text as one of `content` divs, this it hide this div.

If you need to hide all `summary` div's if one of them have same text as one of `content` divs, then

```
    if( char20_of_contents.some( function( content_char_20 ){ return content_char_20 === char20_of_summ; } ) ){

        for( var j = 0; j<l; j++ )
             summarys[j].style.display = 'none'

        console.log( 'found node with same content', summ_node );
        found = true;
        break;
    }
```

UPDATE: hide all summarys in article

```
function get_first_20_chars( node ){
    var content = 'textContent' in node ? node.textContent : node.innerText; //still support ie8?
    var char20 = content.substr(0, 20);
    return char20
}

function hide_summ( article ){
    var summarys = article.getElementsByClassName( "summary" );
    var contents = article.getElementsByClassName( "content" );

    var char20_of_contents = [];
    for( var i = 0, l=contents.length; i<l; i++ ){
        char20_of_contents[i] = get_first_20_chars( contents[i] );
    }

    var found = false;
    for( var i = 0, l=summarys.length; i<l; i++ ){
        var summ_node = summarys[i];
        var char20_of_summ = get_first_20_chars( summ_node );

        for( var j = 0, l_content=char20_of_contents.length; j<l_content; j++ )
            if( char20_of_contents[ j ] === char20_of_summ ){

                for( var k = 0; k<l; k++ )
                    summarys[k].style.display = 'none';
                console.log( 'found node with same content', summ_node );
                found = true
                return
        }
    }

    console.log('nothing found');
}

var articles = document.getElementsByClassName('article');
for( var i = 0, l=articles.length; i<l; i++ ){
    hide_summ( articles[i] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arnial, let me try this  and get back to you

Comment: I've tried the code, it's not working. First char20_of_all_contents is undefined; But even when I define it as an array, I get an error: "o.any is not a function"

Comment: I update code in unswer. Changes: `char20_of_all_contents` -> `char20_of_contents`, `any` -> `some`. Also if `some` is not defined then you can add [polifill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or rewrite it with inner loop.

Comment: Updated again, forget `var` in front of `char20_of_summ`.

Comment: Thanks Arnial, it's working. However it only hides the summary of the first div, and not all the divs of the summary class... How can I fix that?

Comment: Here is how it gets generated : <div class="article-section><div class="summary"></div><div class="content"></div></div>. So basically, I need for each article-section to compare summary div and content div, and if same, hide summary div. Not hide all of them if the summary of the first article is different than its content. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't heck every summary div and  If div have same text as one of content divs, hide this div. It just hides the first div...

Comment: Added code to hide all `summary` in article (if article have `content` with same text). For each article.